# neo4j community edition 2.1.6 server process running even after server stop command executed

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I know at least a few of us had this issue come up...I am issuing the command to start the server and yet it tells me that a server process is still running at 17922...I then try the following:

./bin/neo4j status

And it tells me: "Neo4j Server is not running"

Then I issue the command to start a new server: ./bin/neo4j start

and I get the following:

Another server-process is running with [17922], cannot start a new one. Exiting.

Not looking to run multiple Neo4J servers, so I'd like to stop whatever is running in the background.

Comment: Do you have different installation directories for multiple Neo4j servers? Perhaps you started one from another directory?

Comment: Yes that was the problem.  However I know if need be one can run more than one instance at a time.  It wasn't what I required in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the process is not nicely responding for whatever reason. You might want to inspect the log files (`data/log/*` and `data/graph.db/messages.log`) to get more insight.

To terminate the process use `kill 17922`. If that does not help, `kill -9 17922`.

Comment: thanks Stefan!  Actually I ended up removing Neo4j community edition and reloading it.  Next time I'm just going to use Neo4j from the command-line shell.  It seems to behave a bit better.  If the problem happens again, I will definitely try your suggestions.  Its probably good idea to look at the log files occasionally anyway.